# LAContext Touch ID inside of App extension Keyboard

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, touch-id

I am trying to add touchid to unlock a password protected section of a custom keyboard extension.

When I add this code to the UIInputViewController for the custom keyboard extension, it generates a runtime error

```
let authContext = LAContext()
```

The error is:

> 2015-09-01 22:18:50.524 AS_Custom_KB[21508:2656253] plugin
>   com.example.AS-Custom-KB.AS-Custom-KeyBoard interrupted 2015-09-01
>   22:18:50.545 AS_Custom_KB[21508:2656253] plugin
>   com.example.AS-Custom-KB.AS-Custom-KeyBoard invalidated 2015-09-01
>   22:18:51.635 AS_Custom_KB[21508:2656082]
>   viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)"
>   UserInfo=0x174273f80 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

The same code works fine on the simulator, but doesn't do anything as the simulator doesn't support TouchID.  The code also works fine in a regualar app (and not a custom keyboard extension).

I have tried looking through the LAContext documentation, but didn't find anything about why it might cause an error like this, or any info about not being able to use it from an extension.

Any ideas about why this might be happening, or how to get this working from a custom keyboard extension?  Has anyone been able to get touchid working from a custom keyboard extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 24hours of R&D I found a answer my self, I found answer very simple and settings

Set `RequestsOpenAccess` Yes in your `NSExtensionAttributes`

Comment: I do it like your said. But it doesn't wok. error: ` initWithExistingContext -> (null), Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon was invalidated."`. does it works fine for you ? I want to use Touch ID  in my keyboard extension. I test it in iOS 11.

Comment: @kai Just give full access to your keyboard from Settings > General > Keyboards > Your Custom Keyboard